# How to find WiFi related events\logs in win10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, event-log

Is anyway to find WiFi related events\logs in win10?
My computer is connected to a specific WiFi and i want to know on what date this WiFi is defined in my windows.

Comment: "what date this WiFi is defined in my windows" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @spikey_richie This means on what date the password of this Wi-Fi was entered and this Wi-Fi was defined in the system for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use WifiHistoryView. It is a simple tool that displays the history of connections to wireless networks on your computer. For every event that the computer connected to a wireless network or disconnected from it, the following information is displayed: The date/time that the event occurred, network name (SSID), profile name, network adapter name, BSSID of the router/Access Point, and more...

[WifiHistoryView - Displays history of connections to wireless](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_history_view.html)

Comment: Pretty good for knowing when I was at the office for example. But how far back does this go, it only gave me a few weeks back.